# Echo html and PHP in jQuery syntax

Tags: php, jquery, html, syntax, echo

How do i echo the following HTML and PHP in jQuery to make it render as html?

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: What html are you talking about?

Comment: save  `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` in a variable, like: `var dir = '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>';` then use it in the script src. like: `<script src="'+var+'/js/carousel.js"></script>`

Comment: <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/carousel.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, save it in a variable like @FrayneKonok suggested. or use `.html` inside another `<script>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it inside a variable like

```
var script = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>" + "/js/carousel.js";
```

Watch out for the quote you use.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
$('head').append('<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/carousel.js"></script>')
```

It will add the code at the end of `head` tag. Assuming all your `jquery` library available in `head` tag

**Note:** It will work only if you write this code inside a `php` file

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what u want

```
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/carousel.js"></script>
```